# Angularjs routing not working correctly

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, angularjs, mvvm

```
angular.module('Stations', ['ngRoute'])      
  .config(function ($routeProvider) {
     $routeProvider
     .when('/documents/:stationId', {
               templateUrl: '/Scripts/Modules/checklist/views/index.html',
               controller: 'checklistController'
           })
     .when('/documents/details', {
                templateUrl: '/Scripts/Modules/checklist/views/details.html',
                controller: 'checklistDetailsController'
            })
});
```

Now if i type the url `/stations#/documents/4`, it jumbs to to the documents view and show all the documents in that station. But if i go to the url `stations#/documents/details?Id=3&type=note`, it still go to the documents main view and not the details view.

Could you please give me a hint on what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: It has no idea what you're requesting, so it just displays the details view. You never configured it to handle URLs like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here the router beleives that `details` is a `:stationId`

So it matches the first route `/documents/:stationId` and affects the value `details` to the `stationId`parameter.

You should change the route for the details page to

```
.when('/details', {
```

Or if you want to say that `stationId` must be a number, you can do that with angular ui-router :
https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#regex-parameters

Comment: you're right, it was assuming **stationId** as **details**. but its weird, why angular not able to differentiate the route from **:parameter**? i change the **documents** to **document**, now its working...

Comment: Angular router doesn't know that details is not a valid value for :stationId.

Comment: I added in my answer a link to ui-router, which allows to set a pattern match on a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you should change the route to

```
.when('/documents/details/:id/:note', {... });
```

This would be useful to get the params using `$routeParams` in your controller etc.

Answer (score 0):

Because first route matched is executed and `details` in that URL is considered as stationId. 
Put second route first so that it is matched first. Like this.

```
angular.module('Stations', ['ngRoute']).config(function ($routeProvider) {
 $routeProvider
 .when('/documents/details', {
            templateUrl: '/Scripts/Modules/checklist/views/details.html',
            controller: 'checklistDetailsController'
        })
 .when('/documents/:stationId', {
           templateUrl: '/Scripts/Modules/checklist/views/index.html',
           controller: 'checklistController'
       })

 });
```

But this will mean, if your `stationId` by any chance is the word 'details', then it will be matched to first route and not to the second route. So consider avoiding this type of configuration.

Answer (score -1):

You need to put in the params in the route:

```
.when('/documents/details:documentId', {
    templateUrl: '/Scripts/Modules/checklist/views/details.html',
    controller: 'checklistDetailsController'
});
```

See: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route

Comment: That's not true, you don't need to define the params that you insert after a question mark.